# Can't access $state.current.data in angular ui-router as per documentation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to dynamically update the page title.

Consider a state defined thus:

```
 $stateProvider.state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: '/templates/views/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl',
        data: {title: 'Log in'}
 }
```

In the page HEAD section:

```
<title page-title></title>
```

According [to the documentation, I am supposed to be able to access my custom data property](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects):

```
app.directive("pageTitle", function ($state) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: "{{title}}",
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.title=$state.current.data.title; //wrap this in $watch
            console.log('page state',$state.current.data.title);
        }

    }
});
```

But this returns `undefined`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable is indeed available to the page, but in your directive, you have created an [isolated scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive).  whenever you use the `scope: {}` option on a directive, it creates a scope which is limited to the directive only.

You have two options which will help to solve this issue.

1. You can create the directive without the `scope:{}` option, which would allow the directive full access to the `scope` which exists on the parent page.  The drawback here is that this limits the use of the directive to a single instance per scope.
2. Create a binding in the scope option and pass the variable from the HTML to the directive

Directive: `scope: {title: '=title'}`

HTML: `<title><page-title title="{{$state.current.data.title}}"></page-title></title>`

Comment: Ah, sweet explanation. Thank you.