# Can't access $state.current.data in angular directive with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, coffeescript, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to inject some `$state` data into a directive.  I have:

```
.state 'appStorefront',
  url: '/app/storefront'
  templateUrl: 'partials/app/catalog.html'
  controller: 'appCatalogCtrl'
  data:
    pageTitle: 'my page'
    offscreenCategory: 'Storefront'
```

and then in my `index.html`, I can grab the `pageTitle` just fine, but the `offscreenCategory` is posing problems:

```
<head>
  <!-- works fine -->
  <meta name="description" content="{{ $state.current.data.pageDescription }}">
  ...
</head>
<body>
  <!-- doesn't work -->
  <e-offscreen offscreenCategory="{{ $state.current.data.offscreenCategory }}"></e-offscreen>
</body>
```

I'm trying to pick up `offscreenCategory` in the directive like so:

```
module.directive "eOffscreen", ($state) ->
  templateUrl: 'components/e-offscreen/e-offscreen.html'
  restrict: 'E'
  scope:
    offscreenCategory: '='
  link: (scope, ele, attrs) ->
    console.log $state.current.data.offscreenCategory # undefined

    console.log scope.offscreenCategory # undefined

    scope.$watch 'offscreenCategory', (newVal, oldVal) -> 
      console.log newVal # never runs
```

How do I access `$state.current.data` in the directive?

I have looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897788/cant-access-state-current-data-in-angular-ui-router-as-per-documentation), but this doesn't seem to be working in my case.

Comment: Shouldn't the attribute name be `offscreen-category`, ie `<e-offscreen offscreen-category="{{ ... }}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure but I think it might be as simple as...

```
<e-offscreen offscreen-category="{{ ... }}"></e-offscreen>
```

The reason being that angular directive attributes are normalised in the same way as the directive name. From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> **Note:** These `=attr` attributes in the `scope` option of directives are normalized just like directive names. To bind to the attribute in `<div bind-to-this="thing">`, you'd specify a binding of `=bindToThis`.